# Does parseInt work with percentages?

Tags: javascript, animation, parseint

I'm trying to create a very basic animation that will simply sweep a div container left and right across the browser window. Right now, I'm only trying to get it to move to the right. The thing is, I'm working only with Javascript right now and trying to get it to work - I haven't moved onto jQuery yet. So please bear with me.

My question is, I'm using the parseInt function in javascript to animate the div container's motion across my browser window. It worked well with pixels (px) but doesn't seem to function well with percentages. I specifically want to use percentages because it adjusts to the entire browser window. Here's my code:

```
var animateright

function init(){
    Obj = document.getElementById('box');
    Obj.style.position = "relative";
    Obj.style.left = '0%';
}

function moveRight(){
    Obj.style.left = ''+parseInt(Obj.style.left)+1'%';
    animateright = setInterval(moveRight,100);
}
```

I found it a bit tricky getting the parseInt function to convert to a string which can be concatenated with '%', but the basic premise is that each time I run moveRight(), I want the box to move 1% to the right of the browser window. I think that this is the correct format it would take, unless parseInt isn't parsing the percent sign away from '0%'.

Of course, if anyone has any better method of animating this box with percentages and Javascript (not jQuery) let me know!

Comment: `parseInt` simply takes everything from the beginning of the string to the first non-digit character. It doesn't care what that character is.

Comment: `parseInt('1%')` returns `1` so you should be fine

Comment: missing a `+` between `1` and `'%'`

Comment: Syntax error. Should be: `Obj.style.left = (parseInt(Obj.style.left, 10)+1) + '%';`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in pure CSS3:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/suhix/1/edit)**

```
#box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    animation: moveLeftRight 3s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes moveLeftRight {
    0%   { left: 0%; }
    100% { left: 80%; }
}
```

If you don't like the *linear* move, you can try with *ease* .